# Why v-bind is one-way data binding while v-for can update data from children component in vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

guys. I am reading the book of The Majesty Of Vue.js 2. I am confused with one example in the book.

My question is - why upvote button can modify data of Vue instance which displayed in pre tag while favorite button can not?

It is said that favorite is bound via v-bind directive, which is one way data binding means that children are not able to sync data with parent. But how did story get updated? Two way data binding like v-model?

Here is the code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Vue</title>
</head>
<body>
<div v-cloak id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Let's hear some stories!</h1>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <story v-for="story in stories" :story="story" :favorite="favorite"></story>
        </ul>
        <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<template id="story-template">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ story.writer }} said "{{ story.plot }}"
        Story upvotes {{ story.upvotes }}.
        <button v-show="!story.voted" @click="upvote" class="btn btn-default">Upvote</button>
        <button v-show="!isFavorite" @click="setFavorite" class="btn btn-primary">Favorite</button>

    </li>
</template>
<script src="../../vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('story', {
        template: "#story-template",

        props: ['story', 'favorite'],
        methods: {
            upvote: function () {
                this.story.upvotes += 1;
                this.story.voted = true;
            },
            setFavorite: function () {

                this.favorite = this.story;
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isFavorite: function () {
                return this.story === this.favorite
            }
        }
    });
    window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            stories: [
                {
                    plot: 'My horse is amazing.',
                    writer: 'Mr. Weebl',
                    upvotes: 28,
                    voted: false
                },
                {
                    plot: 'Narwhals invented Shish Kebab.',
                    writer: 'Mr. Weebl',
                    upvotes: 8,
                    voted: false
                },
                {
                    plot: 'The dark side of the Force is stronger.',
                    writer: 'Darth Vader',
                    upvotes: 49,
                    voted: false
                },
                {
                    plot: 'One does not simply walk into Mordor',
                    writer: 'Boromir',
                    upvotes: 74,
                    voted: false
                }
            ],
            favorite: {}
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how objects work in Javascript. When stored in a variable you sir a reference to that object. So when you pass it around, you're actually only passing the reference. Meaning that altering an object (not overwriting!), alters is on all places.

What happens in your example is that you modify the story object. You alter its keys but do not overwrite the object itself. Seeing the app has the same reference to the story object. The changes are shown.

In the case of the favorite however. You get passed the reference of the favorite object. But as soon as you click the favorite button. It swaps the variable to reference the story, but only locally. The app still holds the old reference. This is because you only pass the reference itself and not the parent object.

This is where state managers like Vuex come in to place.